# What's wrong with my cucumber?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, leaves, planting, organic

brown water-soaked, and it starts from the top of cucumber leaves. I put them into a wet condition, but no symptoms of bacterial disease or fungal disease.
Really need help

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your question; if could include an overall illustration & closer illustration of tops & new leaves, cucumber variety, region, watering frequency, nutrient type & amount & frequency, average daytime temperature, average nightime temperature, and soil, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!